# Why does powershell give different result in one-liner than two-liner when converting JSON?

Tags: json, powershell

## Overview

From a powershell 3 prompt,, I want to call a RESTful service, get some JSON, and pretty-print it. I discovered that if I convert the data to a powershell object, and then convert the powershell object back to json, I get back a nice pretty-printed string. However, if I combine the two conversions into a one-liner with a pipe I will get a different result.

**TL;DR:** this:

```
PS> $psobj = $orig | ConvertFrom-JSON
PS> $psobj | ConvertTo-JSON
```

... gives me different result than this:

```
PS> $orig | ConvertFrom-JSON | ConvertTo-JSON
```

## Original data

```
[
  {
    "Type": "1",
    "Name": "QA"
  },
  {
    "Type": "2",
    "Name": "whatver"
  }
]
```

## Doing the conversion in two steps

I'm going to remove the whitespace (so it fits on one line...), convert it to a powershell object, and then convert it back to JSON. This works well, and gives me back the correct data:

```
PS> $orig = '[{"Type": "1","Name": "QA"},{"Type": "2","Name": "DEV"}]'
PS> $psobj = $orig | ConvertFrom-JSON
PS> $psobj | ConvertTo-JSON
[
    {
        "Type":  "1",
        "Name":  "QA"
    },
    {
        "Type":  "2",
        "Name":  "DEV"
    }
]
```

## Combining the two steps with a pipe

However, if I combine those last two statements into a one-liner, I get a different result:

```
PS> $orig | ConvertFrom-JSON | ConvertTo-JSON
{
    "value":  [
                  {
                      "Type":  "1",
                      "Name":  "QA"
                  },
                  {
                      "Type":  "2",
                      "Name":  "DEV"
                  }
              ],
    "Count":  2
}
```

Notice the addition of the keys "value" and "Count". Why is there a difference? I'm sure it has something to do with the desire to return JSON object rather than a JSON array, but I don't understand why the way I do the conversion affects the end result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to wrap the first two operations with parenthesis:

```
PS C:\> ($orig | ConvertFrom-JSON) | ConvertTo-JSON
[
    {
        "Type":  "1",
        "Name":  "QA"
    },
    {
        "Type":  "2",
        "Name":  "DEV"
    }
]
```

The parenthesis allow you to grab the output of the first two operations all at once. Without them, powershell will attempt to parse any objects its gets separately. The collection of `PSCustomObject` resulting from `$orig | ConvertFrom-JSON` contains two `PSCustomObjects` for the 1/QA and 2/DEV pairs, so by piping the output of that collection powershell attempts to handle the key/value pairs one-at-a-time.

Using parenthesis is a shorter way of "grouping" that output and allows you to operate on it without making a variable.

Comment: The workaround (parentheses) is effective, but your explanation is not correct. In fact, `ConvertTo-Json` _not_ handling the input objects one at a time (and instead treating the input collection as a _single object_) is the source of the problem, which stems from `ConvertFrom-Json` sending the array as a _single_ item through the pipeline (which may be a bug).
`1, 2 | ConvertTo-Json` shows that `ConvertTo-Json` handles normal input collections correctly, without the need for parentheses.

Comment: I am using `ConvertTo-Json` on a JSON-based REST endpoint which returns an array. The value I see is `{ "value" : [...], "count" : 5 }`, but I just want to get the value and I am not interested in getting an object with value and count. How do I do this?

Answer (score 21):

Note: The **problem will continue to plague *Windows PowerShell*** (whose latest and *last* version is v5.1), but **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) is *not* affected**.

The existing answers provide an effective *workaround* - enclosing `$orig | ConvertFrom-JSON` in `(...)` - but do not *explain* the problem correctly; also, the workaround cannot be used in all situations.

---

As for ***why* use of an *intermediate variable* did not exhibit the problem**:

- The in-pipeline distinction between emitting an array's elements *one by one* vs. the array *as a whole* (as a single object) is nullified if you collect the output in a *variable*; e.g., `$a = Write-Output 1, 2` is effectively equivalent to `$a = Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2`: while the latter emits array `1, 2` as a *single* object, in both cases `$a` ends up containing a 2-element array.
- Then using array `$a` as pipeline input causes it to be *enumerated*, i.e. sent though the pipeline *element by element*.
- By contrast, *direct* use of `Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2` as pipeline input would send the array *as a whole* through the pipeline,  which is what `ConvertFrom-Json` effectively does.

---

The **problematic behavior** is a combination of **two factors**:

- `ConvertFrom-Json` deviates from normal output behavior by sending *arrays* as *single objects* through the pipeline. That is, **with a JSON string representing an *array*, `ConvertFrom-Json` sends the resulting array of objects as a *single* object through the pipeline**.

  - You can verify `ConvertFrom-Json`'s surprising behavior as follows:

    ```
      PS> '[ "one", "two" ]' | ConvertFrom-Json | Get-Member

      TypeName: System.Object[]  # !! should be: System.String
      ...
    ```
  - If `ConvertFrom-Json` passed its output through the pipeline one by one - as cmdlets normally do - `Get-Member` would instead return the (distinct) types of the *items* in the collection, which is `[System.String]` in this case.

    - **Enclosing a command in `(...)` forces *enumeration* of its output**, which is why `($orig | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json` is an effective workaround.
  - This **behavior was eventually changed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, which now emits the elements of an array one by one, as expected, *unless* you use the `-NoEnumerate` switch.
- The **`System.Array` type - the base type for all arrays - has a `.Count` property defined for it via PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System - see [`Get-Help about_Types.ps1xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml))** in Windows PowerShell, which **causes `ConvertTo-Json` to include that property in the JSON string** it creates, with the array elements included in a sibling `value` property.

  - This **happens only when `ConvertTo-Json` sees an array *as a whole*** as an input object,<sup>[1]</sup> as produced by `ConvertFrom-Json` in this case; e.g., `, (1, 2) | ConvertTo-Json` surfaces the problem (a nested array whose inner array is sent as a single object), but
    `1, 2 | ConvertTo-Json` does not (the array elements are sent individually).
  - This ETS-supplied `.Count` property was effectively obsoleted in PSv3, when arrays implicitly gained a `.Count` property due to PowerShell now surfacing *explicitly* implemented interface members as well, which surfaced the `ICollection.Count` property (additionally, *all* objects were given an *implicit* `.Count` property in an effort to unify the handling of scalars and collections).
  - Sensibly, this ETS property has therefore been removed in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*; see below for a workaround in Windows PowerShell v3+.

---

#### Workaround (*not* needed in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*)

<sup>Tip of the hat, as many times before, to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral).</sup>

Note: This workaround is **PSv3+** by definition, because the `Convert*-Json` cmdlets were only introduced in v3.

Given that the  *ETS*-supplied `.Count` property is (a) the cause of the problem and (b) effectively obsolete in PSv3+, the solution is to simply *remove* it *before* calling `ConvertTo-Json` - it is sufficient to **do this *once* in a session**; it should not affect other commands:

```
 # Remove the redundant ETS-supplied .Count property
 Remove-TypeData -ErrorAction Ignore System.Array
```

With that, the extraneous `.Count` and `.value` properties should have disappeared:

```
 PS> '[ "one", "two" ]' | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json
 [
   "one",
   "two"
 ]
```

The above workaround **also fixes the problem for array-valued *properties***; e.g.:

```
PS> '' | Select-Object @{ n='prop'; e={ @( 1, 2 ) } } | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "prop":  [
                 1,
                 2
             ]
}
```

Without the workaround, the value of `"prop"` would include the extraneous `.Count` and `.value` properties as well.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, the problem surfaces only if an array instance is (invisibly) wrapped in a `[psobject]` instance, which, however, is *invariably* the case when a whole array is passed *via the pipeline*, as all objects passing into and out of the pipeline *invariably* receive a `[psobject]` wrapper. Passing a non-wrapped array *as an argument* therefore does *not* exhibit the symptom, e.g.: `ConvertTo-Json @(1, 2)`; you can provoke the symptom with a `[psobject]` cast: `ConvertTo-Json ([psobject] @(1, 2))`</sup>

Answer (score 4):

First off, why is this happening?

PowerShell automatically wraps multiple objects into a collection called a `PSMemberSet` that has a `Count` property on it. It's basically how PowerShell manages arbitrary arrays of objects. What's happening is that the `Count` property is getting added to the resulting JSON, yielding the undesirable results that you're seeing.

We can prove what I just stated above by doing the following:

```
$Json = @"
[
    {
        "Type":  "1",
        "Name":  "QA"
    },
    {
        "Type":  "2",
        "Name":  "DEV"
    }
]
"@;

# Deserialize the JSON into an array of "PSCustomObject" objects
$Deserialized = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Json;
# Examine the PSBase property of the PowerShell array
# Note the .NET object type name: System.Management.Automation.PSMemberSet
$Deserialized.psbase | Get-Member;
```

Here is the output from the above

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSMemberSet

Name           MemberType            Definition                                                                                                                                                                      
----           ----------            ----------                                                                                                                                                                      
Add            Method                int IList.Add(System.Object value)                                                                                                                                              
Address        Method                System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Address(int )                                                                       
Clear          Method                void IList.Clear()                      
......
......
Count          Property              int Count {get;}
```

You can work around this behavior by referencing the `SyncRoot` property of the `PSMemberSet` (which implements the `ICollection` .NET interface), and passing the value of that property to `ConvertTo-Json`.

Here is a complete, working example:

```
$Json = @"
[
    {
        "Type":  "1",
        "Name":  "QA"
    },
    {
        "Type":  "2",
        "Name":  "DEV"
    }
]
"@;

($Json | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json;
```

The correct (expected) output will be displayed, similar to the following:

```
[
    {
        "Type":  "1",
        "Name":  "QA"
    },
    {
        "Type":  "2",
        "Name":  "DEV"
    }
]
[
    {
        "Type":  "1",
        "Name":  "QA"
    },
    {
        "Type":  "2",
        "Name":  "DEV"
    }
]
```

Comment: While it is true that all PS collections have a `Count` property (and since v3 even most scalars, though not via `psbase`), that is _not_ the source of the problem. `1, 2 | ConvertTo-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @(1, 2)` demonstrate that `ConvertTo-Json` handles input collections correctly. The problem is that `ConvertFrom-Json`, when creating an _array_ of custom objects, inexplicably sends that array as a _single object_ through the pipeline rather than item by item.

Comment: Also, the `.psbase` / `[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberSet]` explanation is incorrect: `.psbase` is simply a (normally hidden) property that PowerShell exposes on _every_ object, for reflecting on its type's members; it is not the object's type itself; PowerShell collects multiple objects output by a pipeline in an`[object[]]` array.

Comment: P.S.: You still present `.SyncRoot` as a workaround in the answer, even though you removed it from the code (which was the right thing to do, because it is unrelated to the workaround; arrays themselves implement `ICollection` too); the reason that the workaround is effective is that `(...)` forces enumeration of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem here. I was able to resolve it by using a `ForEach-Object` and a `PSCustomObject`. Hope it helps you.

```
'' | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{ prop= @( 1, 2 ) }} | ConvertTo-Json
```

It gives this, which is the expected behavior and using cleaner approach:

```
{
  "prop": [
        1,
        2
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is indeed an effective workaround for the problem with `'' | Select-Object @{ n='prop'; e={ @( 1, 2 ) } } | ConvertTo-Json`, but I've since realized that executing the following _once_ in a session makes all other workarounds unnecessary (see my answer for details): `Remove-TypeData System.Array`