# Strange behavior when piping converted JSON into ForEach

Tags: powershell

Why does the following not iterate over the elements of the `System.object[]` array returned by `ConvertFrom-Json`:

```
 ConvertFrom-Json '[1, 2, 3]'   | ForEach-Object  {": $_"}
```

but this does:

```
(ConvertFrom-Json '[1, 2, 3]')  | ForEach-Object  {": $_"}
```

It seems to me that in the first case the whole array gets passed as a parameter to `ForEach` but the reason isn't clear to me.

Update: this appears to be a bug in Powershell related to the conversion of arrays, see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3153)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212718/282783).

Comment: Indeed, this is interesting https://puu.sh/ump6h/bb33b203fc.png

Comment: Ok, so `$conv = ConvertFrom-Json '[1, 2, 3]'; $conv | ForEach {$_.gettype()}` works as expected. Why does the array get unpacked during variable assignment but not when piping it? This doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: Compare to `&{,@(1,2,3)}|% "$_"` v `&{@(1,2,3)}|% "$_"`

Comment: @deorst Bugs, which you are pointed is actually "bugs" in `ConvertTo-Json`, not in `ConvertFrom-Json`. Also, behavior you seeing have nothing to do with `ConvertFrom-Json` in particular. It is totally expected, by me at least, PowerShell behavior. `function f {,(1..5)}; f | % GetType; (f) | % GetType`

Answer (score 2):

Copying from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49136853/696808):

`ConvertFrom-Json` has some odd behavior with pipelines.  The issue is that `ConvertFrom-Json` wraps the JSON array in an array and then *passes the whole array* down the pipeline as one item.  This is fine in most cases, but if the outermost level is a JSON array, then that whole array gets passed as a single object into the pipeline.

Compare:

```
PS> ConvertFrom-Json '[1, 2, 3]' | ForEach-Object  {": $_"}
: 1 2 3

PS> (ConvertFrom-Json '[1, 2, 3]') | ForEach-Object  {": $_"}
: 1
: 2
: 3

PS> $x = ConvertFrom-Json '[1, 2, 3]'
PS> $x | ForEach-Object  {": $_"}
: 1
: 2
: 3
PS> ,$x | ForEach-Object  {": $_"}
: 1 2 3
```

Note with that last example we can duplicate the problem with the unary comma operator.

The issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424) for PowerShell Core 6.