# Powershell Why the difference between the two json contents?

Tags: json, powershell

I have two variables of `Byte[]` type (I chose this type for a specific need, so it need to be retained.) which are declared as:

```
$first = New-Object Byte[] 32
$second = New-Object Byte[] 32
```

and, I initalized each index of both the variables.

Now, I created a hashtable `$List1` as:

```
$List1=@{"First" = $first; "Second" = $second}
```

I am using the syntax below for creating the json file:

```
$List1 | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content  -Path $jsonFile1
```

This is the first json file content:

```
{
"First":  {
             "value":  [
                           210,
                           195,
                           131,
                           176,
                           88,
                           154,
                           57,
                           37,
                           2,
                           75,
                           182,
                           190,
                           156,
                           43,
                           113,
                           199,
                           63,
                           25,
                           109,
                           92,
                           220,
                           91,
                           219,
                           252,
                           113,
                           68,
                           202,
                           12,
                           147,
                           194,
                           36,
                           177
                       ],
             "Count":  32
         },
"Second":  {
           "value":  [
                         238,
                         225,
                         12,
                         172,
                         134,
                         94,
                         42,
                         204,
                         27,
                         78,
                         39,
                         166,
                         229,
                         111,
                         143,
                         254
                     ],
           "Count":  16
       }
}
```

Then I read the first json file into a temporary variable as below:

```
$tempHash = Get-Content -Path $jsonFile1 -Raw| ConvertFrom-Json
```

Since `$tempHash` is a `PSCustomObject`, I create a new hashtable `$List2` as below:

```
$List2 = @{"First" = $tempHash.First.value; "Second"= $tempHash.Second.value}
```

which I use to create the second json file as below:

```
$List2 | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content  -Path $jsonFile2
```

This is the second json file content:

```
    {
"First":  [
             133,
             231,
             19,
             173,
             60,
             50,
             105,
             68,
             38,
             109,
             99,
             155,
             2,
             188,
             216,
             9,
             8,
             225,
             203,
             15,
             167,
             8,
             188,
             76,
             192,
             154,
             183,
             194,
             1,
             122,
             143,
             137
         ],
"Second":  [
           27,
           3,
           57,
           67,
           155,
           145,
           181,
           194,
           250,
           10,
           65,
           90,
           41,
           230,
           243,
           196
       ]
}
```

I am using the same syntax to create both the json files. So, why are their structures different?

**[Edit]**

I suspect, the difference is because of this very syntax:

```
$List1=@{"First" = $first; "Second" = $second}
```

because `Byte[]` type variable does not work as a simple `integer[]` type variable.
Correct me.

**[Edit]**

So, it turns out `Byte[]` type variable has two different keys.
"value" which holds the actual array of byte values, and
"Count" which holds the number of elements in the `Byte[]` variable.
  However, when we invoke the `Byte[]` type variable like:

```
$first
```

which is of `Byte[]` type, we get only the values listed under the "value" key. The value under the "count" key is never displayed in console, yet it is passed to the hashtable somehow.

And, One more point to be noted. If I use:

```
 $List2 = @{"First" = $tempHash.First; "Second"= $tempHash.Second}
```

then, I'll have to use:

```
$List2.First.Value #to get the value of the "First" key
```

and that makes me feel uncomfortable because for the `$List1` hashtable, I only needed to use:

```
 $List1.First #to get the value of the "First" key.
```

**[Workaround]**

I created a hastable `$List` as the original hashtable as below for strictly ***one time use only***:

```
$List | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content  -Path $jsonFile
```

Then, I created two hastables `$List1` and `$List2` as below from the original `$jsonFile` above.

```
 $tempHash = Get-Content -Path $jsonFile -Raw| ConvertFrom-Json
 $List1 = @{"First" = $tempHash.First; "Second" = tempHash.Second}
 $List2 = @{"First" = $tempHash.First; "Second" = tempHash.Second}
```

It helped me keep consistency while referring to their keys and values.

Now, I use

```
#to fetch the values of the "First" keys of both hashtables.
$List1.First.value #and
$List2.First.value
```

Similarly, I do the same for "Second" key for both hashtables `$List1` and `$List2`.

```
#to fetch the values of the "Second" keys of both hashtables.
$List1.Second.value #and
$List2.Second.value
```

[Edit]

It turned out to be a bug in my version of Powershell as ststed by @mklement0 below.
The perfect solution will be to instead use the syntax below as instructed by @mklement0 :

```
# Ensure that the input array is constructed without the extra [psobject] wrapper.
$First = [Byte[]]::new(32)
$Second = [Byte[]]::new(32)
```

Comment: Curious. Even when casting the values in `$temphash` to `[byte[]]` the json output is different. Something fishy seems to be going on during [`ProcessDictionary()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c1c5344a8897262433141ecbc13bb06ac2c4bbef/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/ConvertToJsonCommand.cs#L477) step

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **The result of the first `ConvertTo-Json` call is a *quirk* in *Windows PowerShell* as of v5.1: the resulting JSON should have `First` and `Second` contain an array *directly* rather than an *object* with `value` and `Count` properties, with `value` containing the array.**

  - This behavior has been [fixed in *PowerShell (Core)* (v6+)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/3231); it will most likely *not* get fixed in *Windows* PowerShell, which is no longer actively developed and receives only critical fixes.
    `$a = New-Object Byte[] 2; @{ a = $a } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress` yields:

    - `{"a":[0,0]}` in PowerShell Core v6.0.1 - OK.
    - `{"a":{"value":[0,0],"Count":2}}` in Windows PowerShell v5.1 - BROKEN.
- In your case it is **the use of `New-Object`** that **triggers the quirk**:

  - All cmdlets wrap objects they emit to the success output stream in *mostly* invisible `[psobject]` wrappers.
  - However, in this case the wrapper causes a *change in behavior*: it surfaces the [ETS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) type data still associated with `System.Array` in Windows PowerShell, needlessly in v3+ (see below).
  - For other cases in which meant-to-be-invisible `[psobject]` wrappers cause unexpected changes in behavior, see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).

---

**Workaround**:

At the start of your script/session, run:

```
Remove-TypeData System.Array
```

This removes the obsolete ETS-supplied `.Count` property from all array objects, which makes the problem go away for `[psobject]`-wrapped objects (such as returned by `New-Object`) - for an explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212718/45375).

---

**More cumbersome workarounds**:

The problem goes away if you **ensure that `-is [psobject]` no longer reports true for the input arrays**, which can be done in one of the following ways:

- [PSv5+]: `$First = [Byte[]]::new(32)` - use of an *expression* rather than a command makes the problem go away, because it doesn't create an extra, invisible `[psobject]` wrapper.
- [PSv4-]: `$First = (New-Object Byte[] 32).psobject.BaseObject` - explicitly bypassing the extra `[psobject]` wrapper makes the problem go away.

**Simplified example** (PSv5+, but easily adapted to earlier versions; file operations omitted, because they are incidental to the problem):

```
# Ensure that the input array is constructed without the extra [psobject] wrapper.
$First = [Byte[]]::new(2)

# Construct a hashtable...
$List1 = @{ First = $first }
# ... and convert it to JSON:
($json = $List1 | ConvertTo-Json)
```

The above now correctly yields (*no* extraneous object with `value` and `count` properties):

```
{
    "First":  [
                  0,
                  0
              ]
}
```

Reconverting this JSON string to an object now works as expected:

```
# Re-convert: $tempObj.First then *directly* contains the input array
#             (there is no .Value property anymore).
$tempObj = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Construct a new hashtable...
$List2 = @{ First = $tempObj.First }
# ... and convert it to JSON.
$List2 | ConvertTo-Json
```

The result is the same JSON string as above.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$List2 = @{"First" = $tempHash.First.value; "Second"= $tempHash.Second.value}
```

To this:

```
$List2 = @{"First" = $tempHash.First; "Second"= $tempHash.Second}
```

This will maintain the `value` and `count` structures. On testing, it's also kept the order on the values in the `value` section.

---

**Edit**
To enhance your workaround, you can put in this step so that you can access the values without having to use `.value`:

```
$firstValues = [byte[]]($tempHash.First.value)
$secondValues = [byte[]]($tempHash.Second.value)

$List1 = @{"First" = $firstValues; "Second" = $secondValues}
$List2 = @{"First" = $firstValues; "Second" = $secondValues}
```

---

**Self-Contained Test Script**

```
$jsonFile1 = "jsonFile1.json"
$jsonFile2 = "jsonFile2.json"

$first = New-Object Byte[] 32
$second = New-Object Byte[] 16

foreach($i in 0..($first.COunt -1)){
    $first[$i] = Get-random -minimum 1 -maximum 254
}

foreach($i in 0..($second.COunt -1)){
    $second[$i] = Get-random -minimum 1 -maximum 254
}

$List = @{"First" = $first; "Second" = $second}
$List | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path $jsonFile1

$tempHash = Get-Content -Path $jsonFile1 -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$firstValues = [byte[]]($tempHash.First.value)
$secondValues = [byte[]]($tempHash.Second.value)

$List1 = @{"First" = $firstValues; "Second" = $secondValues}
$List2 = @{"First" = $firstValues; "Second" = $secondValues}
```

Comment: This solves the problem.  However, when we invoke the Byte[] type variable like:

    $first

which is of Byte[] type, we get only the values listed under the "value" key. The value under the "count" key is never displayed in console, yet it is passed to the hashtable somehow.

Comment: One more point to be noted: If I use $List2 = @{"First" = $tempHash.First; "Second"= $tempHash.Second}  now, I ll have to use $List2.First.Value to get the value of the "First" key, and that makes me feel uncomfortable because for the $List1 hashtable, I only needed to use $List1.First to get the value of the "First" key.

Comment: That simplifies the syntax. However, I encountered that json files created using `$List1` and `$List2` as in your editied code will not be consistent with the original json file.