# How to convert powershell array to json using ConvertTo-Json?

Tags: json, powershell

Observe:

```
C:\> [array]@(1,2) | ConvertTo-Json
[
    1,
    2
]
C:\> [array]@(1) | ConvertTo-Json
1
C:\> [array]@() | ConvertTo-Json
C:\>
```

(I expect [1] and [] from the last two cases respectively)

So, if I want to use the standard `ConvertTo-Json` method, how do I do it reliably, even when the array contains 1 or 0 elements?

Note, that post-processing the result is not feasible when the array is part of a complex object converted to json.

**EDIT 1**

```
C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.592
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.592
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


C:\> [array]@(1) | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray
ConvertTo-Json : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AsArray'.
At line:1 char:30
+ [array]@(1) | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray
+                              ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-Json], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToJsonCommand

C:\>
```

Comment: Use the `-AsArray` switch.

Comment: Good pointer, @AdminOfThings, but worth pointing out that `-AsArray` is only supported in PowerShell _Core_; Also note that it doesn't work as one might expect with an empty array: e.g., `ConvertTo-Json -AsArray @() -Compress` yields `[[]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note:

- The answer below discusses providing input to [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Json) *via the pipeline* and the pitfall of using an *empty* or a *single-element* array as input, as well as workarounds.

  - As [js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618172/45375) shows, this pitfall can most easily be avoided if you pass such an array as an *argument* (e.g. `ConvertTo-Json (@1)`), also explained below.
  - For *pipeline* input, [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now offers the convenient `-AsArray` switch as a way to solve the problem, discussed in the bottom section.

---

If `$val` is either the empty array, a scalar, or an array, **use `, @($val) | ConvertTo-Json`** to ensure that it gets serialized as an *array*:

```bash
if (-not $IsCoreCLR) {  # Workaround for Windows PowerShell
 # Only needed once per session.
 Remove-TypeData -ErrorAction Ignore System.Array
}

# Send an empty array, a single object, and an array...
@(), 1, (1, 2) | ForEach-Object { 
  # ... and ensure that each input ($_) serializes as a JSON *array*.
  , @($_) | ConvertTo-Json 
}
```

Note:

- The need for the Windows PowerShell workaround is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48858780/45375).
- **`,`, the *array-construction* operator**, is used here in its unary form to provide an auxiliary, single-element *wrapper* array in order to **send the array *as a whole*** (as a single object) through the pipeline; **by default, sending an array (enumerable) to the pipeline sends its elements *one by one***; note that this is *fundamental* pipeline behavior, irrespective of the cmdlets involved.
- **`@(...)`, the *"array-guarantor"* operator (array-subexpression operator), *ensures* that `$_` is an *array***, that is, it wraps the operand in an array, unless it already is one (loosely speaking<sup>[1]</sup>); this is necessary to cover the case of `$_` containing only a *single* object (scalar; `1` in this case).
- **A general caveat**: **`ConvertTo-Json` quietly limits its serialization depth to `2` by default**, which **results in quiet data loss with more deeply nested input**; use the `-Depth` parameter as needed.

  - [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375) discusses the problem.
  - [GiHub issue #8393](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8393) asked for the treacherous default behavior to be changed; while that didn't happen, PowerShell 7+ now at least omits a *warning* then truncation occurs.

The above yields the following - note how each input was serialized as an array:

```
[]
[
  1
]
[
  1,
  2
]
```

Alternatively, **you can pass the inputs as *arguments* to `ConvertTo-Json`
with `@($val)`**:

```bash
# Same output as above.
@(), 1, (1,2) | ForEach-Object { ConvertTo-Json @($_) }
```

A positional argument implicitly binds to the `-InputObject` parameter, which does *not* enumerate its argument and therefore binds arrays as-is.
Therefore you only need the "array guarantor" `@()` in this case (not also a wrapper array with `,` ).

---

**PowerShell *Core* now offers an `-AsArray` switch**, which directly ensures that the input is serialized as an array, even if there's only a *single* input object:

```bash
PS> 1 | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray
[
  1
]
```

However, given that empty arrays result in *no* data being sent through the pipeline, you **still need a wrapper array if the input is the *empty array* and you then *mustn't* use `-AsArray`**:

```bash
# Note:
#   @() | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray
# would result in NO output.
# Use `, ` to wrap the empty array to ensure it gets sent through
# the pipeline and do NOT use -AsArray
PS> , @() | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

[]
```

Alternatively, again pass the empty array as an *argument*:

```bash
PS> ConvertTo-Json @() -Compress # Do NOT use -AsArray

[]
```

The problem is that **`-AsArray` *unconditionally* wraps its input in a JSON array**, so that something that already is an array is wrapped *again*:

```bash
PS> ConvertTo-Json -AsArray @() -Compress

[[]]  # *nested* empty arrays
```

That `-AsArray` does *not* act as an array "guarantor" the way that `@(...)` does is discussed in [GitHub issue #10952](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10952).

---

<sup>[1] If the operand is a *scalar* (single object), it is wrapped in a single-element `[object[]]`; if the operand already is an array or is an enumerable, the elements are enumerated and captured in a *new* `[object[]]` array.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Finally, a use for -InputObject:

```
convertto-json -InputObject @(1)
[
  1
]

convertto-json -InputObject @() 
[]
```

Comment: Yes, binding to `-InputObject` prevents the array enumeration that the pipeline performs by default; note that `-InputObject` in this case binds _positionally_, so you needn't specify `-InputObject` (which is why I omitted in in my answer); e.g., `ConvertTo-Json @()` will do.