# Converting a String to JSON back to String and again to JSON with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, marshalling, read-eval-print-loop, file-format

I was intrigued with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789365/4531180) example:

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $json = '[ { "hello": 1 } ]'              
PS /home/nicholas> $json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json 
{
  "hello": 1
}
PS /home/nicholas> $json | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json 
[ { "hello": 1 } ]
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json 
{
  "hello": 1
}
PS /home/nicholas>
```

and am interested as to why it won't "round trip" correctly.  Is it really any different?  Seems a difference without distinction, perhaps.

Incidentally, what is powershell converting "from" and "to"?  Help file says:

> DESCRIPTION
> The `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet converts any .NET object to a string in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

here, I suppose, `String`.

---

I'm not seeing that any information is gained or lost in the above [cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/4531180).  Perhaps I'm not understanding the concern.

Comment: This is a known issue and has to do with how PowerShell unrolls arrays into the pipeline. Does this answer your question? [How to convert powershell array to json using ConvertTo-Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617070/how-to-convert-powershell-array-to-json-using-convertto-json)

Comment: it's certainly useful, but I think it has more to do with https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/4531180  and between the two questions there's no need for this q.