# How to use ConvertTo-Json @() on char or string data from PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, type-conversion, read-eval-print-loop

In the context of [converting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58617070/4531180) to and from `JSON`:

perhaps the `integer`'s below are just marking array index?  Yet it's entirely possible to send 1,1,1 so it's not an index.  the "1" might, perhaps, indicate a "depth" then?

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> ConvertTo-Json @(1)  
[
  1
]
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> ConvertTo-Json @(1,a)
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  ConvertTo-Json @(1,a)
     |                     ~
     | Missing expression after ','.

PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> ConvertTo-Json @(1,2)
[
  1,
  2
]
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> ConvertTo-Json @(a)  
a: The term 'a' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
[]
PS /home/nicholas/powershell>
```

why are integers okay:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> ConvertTo-Json @(1,3,9)
[
  1,
  3,
  9
]
PS /home/nicholas/powershell>
```

but not even a single `char`?

Neither it seems are `String` data acceptable.

Comment: JSON has no concept of a `char` type, only strings: `ConvertTo-Json @(1,'a')`

Comment: thx, that answers my question (such as it is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't have any syntax for defining character literals, and bare words (like the `a` in your example) are interpreted as commands, as the error indicates.

If you want to pass the a single `[char]` `a` as a value, there are a number of options:

```
# Convert single-char string to char
[char]'a'
# or
'a' -as [char]

# Index into string
'a'[0]

# Convert from numberic value
97 -as [char]
```

So you could do something like this:

```
PS ~> ConvertTo-Json @(1,'a'[0])
[
    1,
    "a"
]
```

But as you'll notice, the resulting JSON appears to have converted the `[char]` back into a string - and that's because JSON's grammar doesn't have `[char]`'s either.

From [RFC 8259 §3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#page-6):

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string [...]

So converting from `[string]` to `[char]` is in fact completely redundant:

```
PS ~> ConvertTo-Json @(1,'a')
[
    1,
    "a"
]
```