# Powershell converting array to json yields unexpected results

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to dump a powershell array of hash tables to json like this:

```
$body= ,@($someArray | % {
        {
            @{
                name = $_
            }
        }
    })
$body | ConvertTo-Json
```

But this yields this result:

```
{
    "value":  [
                  {
                      "name":  "test"
                  },
                  {
                      "name":  "test-2"
                  }
              ],
    "Count":  2
}
```

Not sure how to only get the value.
If I do `ConvertTo-Json | $body`, I get:

```
[
    [
        {
            "name":  "test",
        },
        {
            "name":  "test-2",
        }
    ]
]
```

I'm doing the `,@()` syntax because otherwise if I only have one object in my array it gets converted to an Hash Table instead of an array.

I am on Powershell 5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Why the difference between the two json contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841191/powershell-why-the-difference-between-the-two-json-contents)

Comment: Your question may have gotten little attention because you tagged it only as `powershell-5.0`, not also as `powershell`.