# Powershell Add-Member - But without "Value" and "Count" elements in JSON

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am successfully adding a member to my JSON, but I end up with unwanted elements. What I am trying to add is the element inside "Value" that is appearing in the resulting JSON.

```
{
"Block1": value1,
"Block2": value2,
"Block3": []
}
```

Then doing the Add-Member cmdlet.

```
$objectFromJson |
  Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Block3" -NotePropertyValue $newblock -Force
```

I realize I do not have to do the **-Force** part, but in my working code, my JSON string is parsed to an object using **ConvertFrom-Json** and that part is effective for my purposes.

There are from 1 to N elements in the array stored in `$newblock`, to be serialized as array-valued property `Block3`.

Unfortunately, I end up with the following:

```
{
"Block1": value1,
"Block2": value2,
"Block3": [ { "value": { <elements of $newblock> }, "Count": <n> } ]
}
```

In the snippet above, `<elements of $newblock>` represent the JSON representation of the `$newblock` array elements, and `<n>` the count of elements in the array.

It is valid JSON, but not what I desire. Instead, I want the elements of `$newblock` to be direct elements of the `Block3` array, without the extraneous wrapper object with the `value` and `Count` properties:

```
{
"Block1": value1,
"Block2": value2,
"Block3": [ <elements of $newblock> ]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr**

- [Your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57578363/45375) avoids the original problem, and is arguably the better approach to begin with: Create the `.Block3` property as an array *via the original JSON* (rather than later via `Add-Member`), and add elements to that array later with `+=`.
- However, you could have fixed the original problem by simply (but obscurely) passing 
  `-NotePropertyValue $newblock.psobject.BaseObject` instead of 
  `-NotePropertyValue $newblock`, which removes the invisible `[psobject]` wrapper around the array stored in `$newblock` that caused the problem. Read on for an explanation.

---

What matters in the end is: **the *array* stored in the `.Block3` property *must not have an invisible `[psobject]` wrapper***, because **in *Windows PowerShell* that causes the array to serialize to JSON wrapped in an *extra object* with `"Count"` and `"values"` properties**.

The extra object stem from the presence of an obsolete ETS (extended-type system) property named `.Count` for arrays, which takes effect for `[psobject]`-wrapped arrays - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212718/45375) for the gory details.

**The problem no longer surfaces in PowerShell [Core] v6+**, because this ETS property has been removed there.

> Add-Member was the wrong approach, since it adds a PSObject or PSCustomObject under the covers.

Actually, `Add-Member` by itself does *not* do that, because the `-NotePropertyValue` parameter is `[object]`-typed, not `[psobject]`-typed.

The array stored in your `$newblock` variable must already have been `[psobject]` wrapped: 
`$newblock -is [psobject]` probably indicates `$true` for you, whereas a regular array does not (e.g., `1, 2 -is [psobject]` is `$false`)

For instance, **an array returned *from a cmdlet, as a whole* will have an invisible `[psobject]` wrapper**, notably when you use the `New-Object` cmdlet: 
`(New-Object string[] 2) -is [psobject]` returns `$true`

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579) for all scenarios in which this invisible extra `[psobject]` wrapper is added, which can cause other subtle behavioral differences as well, which still affect PowerShell [Core] as of v7.0 (but, as stated, *this* particular issue has been fixed by the removal of the ETS property).

---

There are two **general workarounds**:

- **Session-wide**:

  - Before calling `ConvertTo-Json`, run the following command, which removes the obsolete ETS property, after which arrays serialize as expected - whether `[psobject]`-wrapped or not:
    `Remove-TypeData System.Array`
- **For a given array variable**:

  - Use `.psobject.BaseObject` to access the array's unwrapped, underlying .NET array; in your case: `$newblock.psobject.BaseObject`

---

**Examples:**

**Session-wide workaround:**

```bsh
# The problem: Serialize a [psobject]-wrapped array (0, 0):
PS> ConvertTo-Json -InputObject (New-Object int[] 2)
# Note the extra object with the "count" (element count) and "value" property (elements)
{
    "value":  [
                  0,
                  0
              ],
    "Count":  2
}

# Remove the ETS definitions for System.Array
Remove-TypeData System.Array

# Rerun the command:
PS> ConvertTo-Json -InputObject (New-Object int[] 2)
# OK
[
    0,
    0
]
```

**Workaround for a given array variable**:

```bsh
PS> $arr = New-Object int[] 2; ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $arr
# Note the extra object with the "count" (element count) and "value" property (elements)
{
    "value":  [
                  0,
                  0
              ],
    "Count":  2
}

# $arr.psobject.BaseObject bypasses the [psobject] wrapper
PS> ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $arr.psobject.BaseObject
# OK
[
    0,
    0
]
```

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks for the in-depth analysis. I hope our efforts in the end help others. Cheers.

Comment: Certainly helped me!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my issue was as follows (pseudo code):

```
$json = @"
{
"Block1": value1,
"Block2": value2,
"Block3": []
}
"@

$objFromJson = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$listCount = ($newblock.ToCharArray() | Where-Object ($_ -eq ";" | Measure-Object).Count + 1

for($i = 0; $i -lt $listCount; $i++) {
  $newJson = @{ element1 = value1; element2 = value2; etc. }
  $objFromJson.Block3 += $newJson
}

$objFromJson | ConvertTo-Json
```

The part I had issues with was that `Add-Member` was the wrong approach, since it adds a PSObject or PSCustomObject under the covers.

Thanks to @mklement0 for pointing me to the root cause of my question.