# save powershell content in as JSON with empty value

Tags: c#, json, powershell

I have to save some informations using command `Get-NetFirewallRule`, and save them in a .JSON file. This is how I have done

```
Get-NetFirewallRule  |
select-object -Property Name,
DisplayName,
DisplayGroup,
@{Name='Protocol';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).Protocol}},
@{Name='LocalPort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).LocalPort}},
@{Name='RemotePort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).RemotePort}},
@{Name='RemoteAddress';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter).RemoteAddress}},
Enabled,
Profile,
Direction,
Action |
ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\firewall.txt"
```

and the output file is this (this is a little part of file)

```
        "Name":  "Microsoft-Windows-PeerDist-WSD-Out",
        "DisplayName":  "BranchCache Peer Discovery (WSD-Out)",
        "DisplayGroup":  "BranchCache - Peer Discovery (Uses WSD)",
        "Protocol":  "UDP",
        "LocalPort":  "Any",
        "RemotePort":  "3702",
        "RemoteAddress":  "LocalSubnet",
        "Enabled":  2,
        "Profile":  0,
        "Direction":  2,
        "Action":  2
    },
    {
        "Name":  "Microsoft-Windows-PeerDist-HostedServer-In",
        "DisplayName":  "BranchCache Hosted Cache Server (HTTP-In)",
        "DisplayGroup":  "BranchCache - Hosted Cache Server (Uses HTTPS)",
        "Protocol":  "TCP",
        "LocalPort":  {
                          "value":  [
                                        "80",
                                        "443"
                                    ],
                          "Count":  2
                      },
        "RemotePort":  "Any",
        "RemoteAddress":  "Any",
        "Enabled":  2,
        "Profile":  0,
        "Direction":  1,
        "Action":  2
    }
```

As you can see, powershell save the LocalPort in 2 different ways: the first with 1 value, and the second with 2 value and Count; in my code (C#) I wrote this to read my JSON file

```
string file = File.ReadAllText(MainWindow.path + @"\..\..\misc\json\FirewallRules.json");
List<GetSetFRules> rulesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetSetFRules>>(file);
```

but there is a problem; the class `GetSetFRules` cannot save the content of JSON, because the format in JSON isn't the same for each rules

```
 class GetSetFRules
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayGroup { get; set; }
        public string Protocol { get; set; }
        public Localport LocalPort { get; set; }
        public string RemotePort { get; set; }
        public string RemoteAddress { get; set; }
        public int Enabled { get; set; }
        public int Profile { get; set; }
        public int Direction { get; set; }
        public int Action { get; set; }
    }

    public class Localport
    {
        public string[] value { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

So, the question is, Is there a way to save each rules with empty value like this?

```
[...]"LocalPort":  "Any",[...]
```

⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇

```
[...]"LocalPort":  {
                          "value":  [
                                        "Any",
                                    ],
                          "Count":  1
                      }[...]
```

or this

```
[...]"LocalPort":  {
                          "value":  [
                                        "",
                                    ],
                          "Count":  0
                      }[...]
```

Comment: Teo230, my suggestion is to use a JSON parser that supports a different parsing mechanism instead of (de)serialization. I would propably use one that supports [JSONPath](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath), like [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). In such case you'll have the complete control on how to build the instances loaded with the data you need.

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: yes, I think (and hope) that this could help you: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the output from `($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).LocalPort` in your calculated `LocalPort` property is *array*-typed, which you can ensure as follows:

```bash
@{
  Name='LocalPort'
  Expression={ , [array] ($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).LocalPort }
}
```

- Cast `[array]` ensures that the command output is treated as an array, even if only a *single* value such as `Any` is output.

  - Alternatively, use `@(($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).LocalPort)`, i.e. `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--).
- The unary form of `,`, the [array-constructor ("comma") operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), wraps the resulting array in an aux. temporary array that prevents a *single*-element array from getting unwrapped when the script block's (`{ ... }`) output is assigned to the `Expression` hashtable entry.

As an aside: As Theo points out [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59457188/45375), along with an optimization, calling `Get-NetFireWallPortFilter` *multiple* times for the same input object, across multiple calculated properties, is inefficient and slows your command down.

---

The above will give you the desired JSON representation consistently, but there is a **caveat**:

The JSON representation created by `ConvertTo-Json` for arrays via an *object*, containing a `value` property with the array elements, and a `count` property with the element count, should be considered a *bug*, as arrays should simply be represented as *JSON arrays*:

That is, something like:

```bash
, (80, 443) | ConvertTo-Json
```

*should* yield:

```bash
# OK: This is how it works in PowerShell v6+
[
  80,
  443
]
```

and *not*:

```bash
# BUG in Windows PowerShell v5.1
{
    "value":  [
                  80,
                  443
              ],
    "Count":  2
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57599481/45375) discusses the details, but note that running the following *once* in a given Windows PowerShell session can be used to fix the problem:

```bash
# Run this once per session, before calling ConvertTo-Json, to 
# fix the JSON array serialization problem:
Remove-TypeData System.Array -ErrorAction Ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the solution

Replace class `GetSetFRules` with class `dynamic`

```
List<dynamic> rulesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(file);
```

Comment: With this method the programm won't give you error, but the output will be the same in json file

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with _the output will be the same in json file_. Does that mean you still do not get the desired output?

Comment: Glad to hear my answer worked for you, @Teo230. Given that this answer isn't really effective, please consider amending or removing it, along with your other answer that is really more of a clarification than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

On my Win10 machine, using your Powershell code also shows array output for `RemotePort` and `Protocol`. I believe it is better not to try and adapt all items to have that kind of output, but list all rule objects as-is, so they all have a single value for these properties.

Also, you could speed this up a little by not performing `Get-NetFirewallPortFilter` multiple times:

```
# Retrieve every firewall rule object as single object.
# All of these objects will have properties 'LocalPort', RemotePort, 'Protocol'
# listed as single string values; not as array values in the output
Get-NetFirewallRule | ForEach-Object {
    $portFilter = $_ | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter
    $_ | Select-Object -Property Name,
    DisplayName,
    DisplayGroup,
    @{Name='Protocol';Expression={$portFilter.Protocol}},
    @{Name='LocalPort';Expression={$portFilter.LocalPort}},
    @{Name='RemotePort';Expression={$portFilter.RemotePort}},
    @{Name='RemoteAddress';Expression={($_ | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter).RemoteAddress}},
    Enabled,
    Profile,
    Direction,
    Action 
} | Sort-Object DisplayName | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\firewall.txt"
```

Partial output:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "Name":  "{56BC7333-582E-45E8-9249-F88002B598E9}",
>         "DisplayName":  "Microsoft Management Console",
>         "DisplayGroup":  null,
>         "Protocol":  "TCP",
>         "LocalPort":  "Any",
>         "RemotePort":  "Any",
>         "RemoteAddress":  "Any",
>         "Enabled":  1,
>         "Profile":  4,
>         "Direction":  1,
>         "Action":  4
>     },
>     {
>         "Name":  "{C3F4E91A-65F5-4805-8F6B-86C6ECA5F4EE}",
>         "DisplayName":  "Microsoft Management Console",
>         "DisplayGroup":  null,
>         "Protocol":  "UDP",
>         "LocalPort":  "Any",
>         "RemotePort":  "Any",
>         "RemoteAddress":  "Any",
>         "Enabled":  1,
>         "Profile":  4,
>         "Direction":  1,
>         "Action":  4
>     },
>     {
>         "Name":  "UDP Query User{A8997866-770C-417E-AE45-2436717836E8}C:\\windows\\system32\\mmc.exe",
>         "DisplayName":  "Microsoft Management Console",
>         "DisplayGroup":  null,
>         "Protocol":  "UDP",
>         "LocalPort":  "Any",
>         "RemotePort":  "Any",
>         "RemoteAddress":  "Any",
>         "Enabled":  1,
>         "Profile":  2,
>         "Direction":  1,
>         "Action":  2
>     },
>     {
>         "Name":  "TCP Query User{C99F0EF2-8891-4B2D-B389-4A3F8B66638A}C:\\windows\\system32\\mmc.exe",
>         "DisplayName":  "Microsoft Management Console",
>         "DisplayGroup":  null,
>         "Protocol":  "TCP",
>         "LocalPort":  "Any",
>         "RemotePort":  "Any",
>         "RemoteAddress":  "Any",
>         "Enabled":  1,
>         "Profile":  2,
>         "Direction":  1,
>         "Action":  2
>     }
> ]
> ```

Comment: @Teo230 Yes, every firewall rule is its own object in the result array because of the `ForEach-Object`