# Powershell - Trying to create JSON output with cumulative nested properties

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, nested

I have API calls returning results stored as a CustomObject which in turn each make another call to return one or more related results using a nested foreach loop.  The results are stored in binary files and that works fine.  I am trying to create a nested JSON file for the metadata.

Source:  ParentResult1 properties

- Name
- TotalSize
- FileCount
- Files

Sub Result of Files

- FileName
- Checksum

Ideally I want to create a json that looks like this:

```
[{ "Name": "Value1", "TotalSize": 15, "FileCount": 2, "Files": [{"FileName": "File1", "Checksum": "abc"},{"FileName": "File2", "Checksum": "abc"}]},{ "Name": "Value2", "TotalSize": 15, "FileCount": 2, "Files": [{"FileName": "File3", "Checksum": "abc"},{"FileName": "File4", "Checksum": "abc"}]}]
```

The part I'm struggling with is the nested foreach loop that gets the file information and updates the nested "files" property array with the new value(s).

Comment: Can you create a [mre] of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576341/powershell-add-member-but-without-value-and-count-elements-in-json) using this command inside the outside foreach loop

```
$ExportStatusResults[$i] | Add-Member -Name "Files" -Value $files.psobject.BaseObject -MemberType NoteProperty -force
```