# PowerShell and Convertto-JSON Value and Count

Tags: json, powershell

When i run this code:

```
$TestJSON = @{
    name1="value1";
    name2="value2";    
}
  
function Get-JSON {
    
    $allJSON = @()
    $allJSON += $TestJSON
    return ,@($allJSON)
}

Get-JSON | convertto-json
```

The output is:

```
{
    "value":  [
                  {
                      "name1":  "value1",
                      "name2":  "value2"
                  }
              ],
    "Count":  1
}
```

Where is value and count coming from?  The only way I get rid of them is by putting brackets around Get-JSON like so:

(Get-JSON) | convertto-json

Is there any way to fix this from the function as opposed to having to encase Get-JSON with brackets?  So I can call:

Get-JSON | convertto-json

instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your symptom implies that you're using *Windows PowerShell*.

- Your code would work fine as-is in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)

> Is there any way to fix this from the function as opposed to having to encase Get-JSON with brackets

The only way to achieve that is to run `Remove-TypeData -ErrorAction Ignore System.Array` *first*, which removes the unnecessary ETS type data associated with arrays in Windows PowerShell, which is the cause of the unwanted array serialization, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57599481/45375).

This call is only required *once per PowerShell session*, and takes effect session-globally.