# Add key value pair to json file with powershell

Tags: json, powershell, parsing

I've a json like this, I want to add a line key:value for each line in my file.

For example add a comma and the value KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-01 before the curly bracket.

```
 [
     {
       "name": "/subscriptions/uifaghy78923/resourceGroups/KC-NA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-01"
     },
     {
       "name": "/subscriptions/uifaghy78923/resourceGroups/KC-NA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-02"
     }
    ]

$file="pathtojson"

$jsonContent = Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Json;


$appserviceplan= $jsonContent.name;

foreach ($app in $appserviceplan) {
$app.Split('/')[8]
}
```

I'd like to add the corrisponding $app.Split('/')[8] in every line in order to have

```
     "name": "/subscriptions/uifaghy78923/resourceGroups/KC-NA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-01", "value": "KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-01"
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Json is an array of objects, I think the obvious way is to iterate through this list of objects and for each of them output a new object including the `value` property. The easiest way is to use `Select-Object`.

Something like this:

```
$file = "D:\blah.json"
$json = Get-Content $file -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Select-Object name, @{Name = 'value'; Expression = {($_.name -split '/')[8]}}
} | ConvertTo-Json

$json
```

Result:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "name":  "/subscriptions/uifaghy78923/resourceGroups/KC-NA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-01",
>         "value":  "KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-01"
>     },
>     {
>         "name":  "/subscriptions/uifaghy78923/resourceGroups/KC-NA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-02",
>         "value":  "KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-02"
>     }
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ConvertTo-Json` should work for you:

```
(Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Json) | 
    Select-Object -Property *, @{name ="value"; expression={($_.name -split '/')[8]}} | 
    ConvertTo-Json |
    Out-File -FilePath .\newdata.json
```

This takes all of the existing properties from each object (originally just `name`) and adds a new property called `value` with a value of `($_.name -split '/')[8]`.

It then converts the resulting objects back to JSON using `ConvertTo-Json` which, for your sample data, ends up as:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "name":  "/subscriptions/uifaghy78923/resourceGroups/KC-NA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-01",
>         "value":  "KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-01"
>     },
>     {
>         "name":  "/subscriptions/uifaghy78923/resourceGroups/KC-NA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-02",
>         "value":  "KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-02"
>     }
> ]
> ```

Also note that wrapping `(Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Json)` in parentheses may be required as described in this [excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212718/408817).

Comment: The script run, add the filed in the file, but I get this error and the value for each line is the same. Select-Object : The property cannot be processed because the property "value" already exists. Select-Object -Property *, @{name ="value"; expression={($_.name
    + CategoryInfo :InvalidOperation: (@{name=/subscri...PROJECT-DEV-02}:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyExistingUserSpecifiedPropertyNoExpand,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand. I want to add for each line the corrisponding $_.name -split '/')[8]} in the json file.

Comment: That would happen if your input file already had “value” as a property.  Is that the case?

Comment: No, there wasn't.

Comment: Is this still the original content of your file?
`
 [
     {
       "name": "/subscriptions/uifaghy78923/resourceGroups/KC-NA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-01"
     },
     {
       "name": "/subscriptions/uifaghy78923/resourceGroups/KC-NA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/KC-NA-asplan-PROJECTS-DEV-02"
     }
    ]
`