# How to convert json output to array/list using Powershell (to json output)

Tags: powershell

Want to convert json output to array or list using Powershell.

I have tried converting the output using `ConvertFrom-Json`, then fetching the key Name and Values.  Need suggestion.

json Output:

```
{
    "demo1": {
        "type": [
            "tuple",
            [
                [
                    "list",
                    "string"
                ],
                [
                    "list",
                    "string"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "value": [
            [
                "123"
            ],
            [
                "456"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "demo2": {
        "type": [
            "tuple",
            [
                "string",
                "string"
            ]
        ],
        "value": [
            "abc",
            "xyz"
        ]
    }
}
```

Using Powershell want to convert it as below:

```
demo1 = [["123"],["456"]]
demo2 = ["abc","xyz"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK so you want to just get the property "value" and make that into a array?

Comment: yes, want to get output in array @ArcSet

Comment: Please mark as correct answer if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: is it possible to display the output as I mentioned in expected output. I am getting this output, but not in the expected way

Comment: you want the out as a string? or a array? you said in the post as a array...
I am confused on exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: sorry, if I confused. I want output similar to : ```demo1 = [["123"],["456"]]``` and 
```demo2 = ["abc","xyz"] ```.

Comment: so, when I will print demo1 value, it should print as [["123"],["456"]] and for demo2 it will be ["abc","xyz"]

Comment: I think what i am saying is what you are asking for doesn't makes since. You asked for Arrays like `$Demo1 = "123", "456"`. Are you asking for a sting like `$demo1 = "[["123"],["456"]]"` or are you asking for an array of 2 string `$array = "demo1 = [["123"],["456"]]", "demo2 = ["abc","xyz"]"`

Comment: yes,asking output like this ```$demo1 = "[["123"],["456"]]"```, a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a pretty straightforward use of convertfrom-json:

```
$a = get-content file.json | convertfrom-json

$a.demo1.value
123
456

$a.demo2.value
abc
xyz
```

You want it as json?

```
$a.demo1.value | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
[["123"],["456"]]

$a.demo2.value | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
["abc","xyz"]
```

Comment: but, I want a output like : ```demo1 = [["123"],["456"]] ``` and ```demo2 = ["abc","xyz"] ```. As I want to store the values also.

Comment: @user47, are you thinking about Python or why do you use these brackets? `$a.demo1.value` is a list and can be stored.

Comment: @Alex_P, solved my problem, my mistake. not converting back to JSON. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
$t = '{
    "demo1": {
        "type": [
            "tuple",
            [
                [
                    "list",
                    "string"
                ],
                [
                    "list",
                    "string"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "value": [
            [
                "123"
            ],
            [
                "456"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "demo2": {
        "type": [
            "tuple",
            [
                "string",
                "string"
            ]
        ],
        "value": [
            "abc",
            "xyz"
        ]
    }
}'

$t = ConvertFrom-Json $t 


$t | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'} | foreach {
$element = $_.Name

echo 'Property Name: '
echo $element
echo 'Elements: '
echo ($t.$element.value | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99)

}
```

At this point, powershell core seems to behave slightly different than v3-5, so you while powershell core will give you directly the correct result older versions will need some extra handling at this point, see here: [Why does powershell give different result in one-liner than two-liner when converting JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848507/why-does-powershell-give-different-result-in-one-liner-than-two-liner-when-conve)