# How to reference Azure policy set parameters in policy rule correctly?

Tags: azure, policy, azure-cli

I have following policy rule. Finally it should check existence of a resourcegroup on subscription level. If it does not exist, a remediation task deployment should be started. I would like to pass parameters to this rule.

```
{
    "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions"
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "DeployIfNotExists",
        "details": {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups",
            "name": "my_resource_group",
            "roleDefinitionIds": [
                "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{builtinroleGUID}"
            ],
            "existenceScope": "Subscription",
            "existenceCondition": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "equals": "parameters('resourceGroup')"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "deploymentScope": "Subscription",
            "deployment": {
                "location": "westeurope",
                "properties": {
                    "mode": "incremental",
                    "parameters": {
                        "targetResourceGroup": {
                            "value": "[parameters('resourceGroup')]"
                        },
                        "ascWorkflowName": {
                            "value": "[parameters('securityAutomationWorkflowName')]"
                        },
                        "location": {
                            "value": "[parameters('location')]"
                        },
                        "logicAppName": {
                            "value": "[parameters('logicAppName')]"
                        },
                        "logicAppSubscription": {
                            "value": "[parameters('logicAppSubscription')]"
                        }
                    },
                    "template": {
                        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                        "parameters": {
                            "targetResourceGroup": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ascWorkflowName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "location": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "defaultValue": "westeurope"
                            },
                            "logicAppName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "logicAppSubscription": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "variables": {
                            "logicAppName": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
                            "logicAppTriggerName": "When_an_Azure_Security_Center_Recommendation_is_created_or_triggered",
                            "logicAppResourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('logicAppSubscription'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('targetResourceGroup') , '/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/', variables('logicAppName'))]",
                            "ascWorkflowTriggerId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('logicAppSubscription'),  '/resourceGroups/', parameters('targetResourceGroup') , '/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/', variables('logicAppName') ,'/triggers/',  variables('logicAppTriggerName'))]"
                        },
                        "resources": [
                            {
                                "apiVersion": "2019-01-01-preview",
                                "name": "[parameters('ascWorkflowName')]",
                                "type": "Microsoft.Security/automations",
                                "location": "westeurope",
                                "tags": {},
                                "properties": {
                                    "description": "Workflow to push security center recommendations to our logicApp that routes it to serviceNow",
                                    "isEnabled": true,
                                    "scopes": [
                                        {
                                            "description": "[concat('scope for current subscriptionId:', subscription().subscriptionId)]",
                                            "scopePath": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId)]"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "sources": [
                                        {
                                            "eventSource": "Assessments",
                                            "ruleSets": [
                                                {
                                                    "rules": [
                                                        {
                                                            "propertyJPath": "type",
                                                            "propertyType": "String",
                                                            "expectedValue": "Microsoft.Security/assessments",
                                                            "operator": "Contains"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "actions": [
                                        {
                                            "logicAppResourceId": "[variables('logicAppResourceId')]",
                                            "actionType": "LogicApp",
                                            "uri": "[listCallbackUrl(variables('ascWorkflowTriggerId'), '2016-06-01').value]"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup I would expect that the resourceGroup parameter reference links to the parameter of the parent policy-set /initiative.
But what I get is an error using the azure-cli in powershell. Why do I get the error?

```
function ConvertTo-PolicyJson {
    param (
        [PSCustomObject] $inputObject
    )
    # See this issue with convertto-json array serialization problem - 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848507/why-does-powershell-give-different-result-in-one-liner-than-two-liner-when-conve/38212718#38212718
    # Remove the redundant ETS-supplied .Count property
    $removed = Remove-TypeData System.Array -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
    $json = ConvertTo-Json $inputObject  -Depth 10
    return $json.replace('"', '\"').replace("`n","").replace("`r","" )
}

...

$policyRuleParametersJson = ConvertTo-PolicyJson @{
    "resourceGroup"                  = @{
        "type"         = "String"
        "defaultValue" = "$ResourceGroup"
        "metadata"     = @{
            "description" = "The resource group where the resources are located in"
            "displayName" = "Resource group"
            "strongType"  = "existingResourceGroups"
        }
    }}

...


$policySetJson = ConvertTo-PolicyJson @(
    @{
        "policyDefinitionId" = "/subscriptions/$Subscription/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/$ResourceGroupExistsPolicyName"
        "parameters" = @{
            "resourceGroup" = @{ 
                "value" = "my_resource_group" 
            }  }
...


$policyDefinitionSetCreateResult = az policy set-definition create `
    --subscription $Subscription `
    --definitions $policySetJson `
    --params $policyRuleParametersJson `
    --name $PolicySetName `
    --description $PolicySetDescription `
    --display-name $PolicySetDisplayName
```

The error I am getting is:

```
The policy set 'my-policy-set' has defined parameters 'resourceGroup' which are not used in referenced policy definitions. Please either remove these parameters from the definition or ensure that they are used.
```

But I have used the resourceGroup parameter as far as I know.
By the way I condensed the error example to one parameter (resourceGroup). Finally I would like to use more parameters.

Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to give an answer on my own question.

I guess you need to use uppercase initiative parameter names that do not collide with child parameter names. For instance use RESOURCEGROUP_1 or RESOURCEGROUP if your policy parameter has been named resourceGroup. There seems to be an implicit naming convention for those parameter names that has not been documented properly.